# Is it possible to do a times and date plot by reading the data from temporary file?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

I have twitter data in a textfile in a following format "RT Find out how AZ is targeting escape pathways to further personalise breastcancer treatment SABCS14  Thu Dec 11 03:09:12 +0000 2014".  So from this i need to find same tweets with same text and get their time and date. After that i have to do a time and date plot. Following is my code what i have tried.

```
import matplotlib
import os
import tempfile
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode = 'w+t')
count = 0
f = open('bcd.txt','r')
lines =  f.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    try:
        next_line = lines[i+1]
    except IndexError:
        continue

    if line == next_line:
       count +=1
       temp.writelines([line+'\n'])


temp.seek(0)

for line in temp:
    line.split('\t')
```

First i have compared the line with next line, then i wrote that into a temporary file then tried to go through that temporary file and extract the time and date of particular tweets but i was unsuccessful. Anykind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
link to data file 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxE3rA3-6F8eVGVwOFlVRjNFTUE/view?usp=sharing